# ActiveRecord limit users returned from a collection of company_ids

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an array of company_ids
In the `User` model, I would like to find_by company_ids, but for each company_id, the user list returned should not exceed 5 users. How can I do that.

I have tried doing this

```
User.where(company_id: [1, 2, 3]).group('users.company_id').having('count(company_id) <= 5')
```

But this will return only those set where users in a company are not more than 5. Moreover, this wont return all the records.

What I am trying to do is, for `company_ids = [1, 2, 3]`, the collection should be able to return at max 5 users for company_id 1, then company_id 2, then company_id 3, and not load all the users for all those company_ids.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using MySql.

Comment: What version @arjun?

Comment: @SebastianPalma MySql version is 5.7.28, Rails version 5.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the further you can due to your MySQL version is just using `UNION ALL`.

You can create a query selecting the users by their `company_id` and then applying the `LIMIT`:

```
(select * from users where company_id = 1 LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(select * from users where company_id = 2 LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(select * from users where company_id = 3 LIMIT 2)
```

As Rails doesn't have a built-in support for `UNION` queries, you can create your own statement:

```
sql = [1, 2, 3].map { |id| "(SELECT * FROM users WHERE company_id = #{id} LIMIT 2)" }
               .join(" UNION ALL ")
User.find_by_sql(sql)
```

---

Update using MySQL8+

```
SELECT id, name, company_id
FROM (
  SELECT id, name, company_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS company_user
  FROM users
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY company_id)
) users
WHERE company_user <= 2;
```

The ActiveRecord way would be:

```
User
  .select(:id, :name, :company_id)
  .from(
    User.select(:id, :name, :company_id, 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS company_user')
        .from('users WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY company_id)')
  )
  .where('company_user <= 2')
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. You mentioned based on my MySql version UNION ALL can do the work. Is there any other way to do this if it were a different version?

Comment: Yes, in MySQL 8 you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION BY`. Check the updated answer.